# Declaring $(this) variable before actual function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, global-variables

I have to make a bunch of checks based on ID's of some elements, but those all differ a little.

So I made a bunch of functions, and instead of always having to repeat `$(this).children ...` I wanted to have a short variable for that. But when I declare it outside the actual function, I get `undefined`.

Isn't the code supposed to work like: Hmm, so there's a variable using *this*, and right now *this* is a *list*, then I'll become `$('ul').children ...` ? 
What logic is it following and how should I fix it?

Minified example of issue:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var thisID = $(this).attr('id');

  function replaceContent(id) {
    $('#' + id).html('new content, and the ID is: ' + thisID);
  }

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    alert(thisID);
    // replaceContent(thisID);
    replaceContent(hello);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello">abc</div>

<div id="result"></div>

<button>button</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2kduy9vp/84/

Comment: One does not simply declare `this`, it exists in different contexts depending on where in the code it's used.  `this` in your document.ready function refers to the browser window object.  `this` in an event handler usually refers to the browser element that was clicked on/changed/submitted, and that's what I think you're looking for.

Comment: @James but why doesn't **this** become the event handler that has been clicked (even if it was the window when I declared it), when it's used inside a function ? Shouldn't it "check again" what **this** currently refers to ?That's what I don't understand.

Comment: No it won't check again.  thisID will always have the value of the ID of the window object.  If you put `thisID = this.id` in the button click handler it would be updated to the id of the clicked button however.

Comment: The variable doesn't "remember" how it was initialized. The same way if you do `var a = 2; var b = a + 1;` the variable `b` doesn't change if you change the value of `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not exactly how "this" works. When you are storing "this" under the "$(document).ready" you'll have its reference being the 'document', not the element you'll have later. "this" is not exactly a variable, but more of a keyword to the current element under that scope.

To solve your 'problem', you might want to change to something like this, if you really want to change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getID(element) {
    return $(element).attr('id');
  }

  function replaceContent(id) {
    $('#' + id).html('new content, and the ID is: ' + id);
  }

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var thisID = getID(this);
    replaceContent(thisID);
    replaceContent('hello');
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are going for. You can only use `this` when you are in the scope/context of a list of children. You can create a method to pass different ids to do logic on a given id also.

```js
// Example one
var hightLightItem = function(div) {
    $(div).css("color", "blue"); // Putting this in here will refer to window
}
hightLightItem("#One");

// Example Two
var childs = $("#A-bunch-of-items2").children();

childs.each(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "red"); // this in here refers to the child at each iteration of .each()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A-bunch-of-items">
  <div id="One">One</div>
  <div id="Two">Two</div>
  <div id="Three">Three</div>
  <div id="Four">Four</div>
  <div id="Five">Five</div>
  <div id="Six">Six</div>
</div>
<div id="A-bunch-of-items2">
  <div id="One">One</div>
  <div id="Two">Two</div>
  <div id="Three">Three</div>
  <div id="Four">Four</div>
  <div id="Five">Five</div>
  <div id="Six">Six</div>
</div>
```